# How to add types to computed in composition api vue 3

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

The problem - I try to add type to computed but I have error: `Overload 1 of 2, '(getter: ComputedGetter<AuthFormType>, debugOptions?: DebuggerOptions | undefined): ComputedRef<AuthFormType>', gave the following error`.
How type can be added to computed?

Auth.vue

```
type AuthFormType = 'Form1' | 'Form2';
const getForm = computed<AuthFormType>(
  () => tabs.value.find((tab) => tab.id === currentTab.value)!.component, // will return Form1 or Form2
);
```

If I add simple type - string, like in doc https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-computed if will work, but I need to add type AuthFormType

Answer (score 1):

Computed properties don't normally need to be typed since their typing is inferred by the return value.
[image]

As my VS Code "peek type definition" hover action shows, the correct type of `ComputedRef<AuthFormType>` is inferred correctly.  If you still want to explicitely type the computed property you can import and use that same `ComputedRef` interface

```js
import { computed, ref, ComputedRef } from 'vue';
import type { Ref } from 'vue';

interface tabObj {
  id: number;
  component: AuthFormType;
}
const tabs: Ref<tabObj[]> = ref([]);
const currentTab = ref(0);

type AuthFormType = 'Form1' | 'Form2';
const getForm: ComputedRef<AuthFormType> = computed(
  (): AuthFormType =>
    tabs.value.find(tab => tab.id === currentTab.value)!.component
);
```